# ¿Qué significa "las" en la frase "se las ingenia"? ¿Por qué nunca aparece "se los ingenia"?

Tags: expresiones

La herramienta de contexto reverso.net me dio muchos ejemplos de "[se las ingenia](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/se+las+ingenia)" pero ninguno de "[se los ingenia](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/se+los+ingenia)".  De la misma manera, aparece "[se las arregla](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/se+las+arregla)" pero casi nunca "[se los arregla](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/se+los+arregla)".

Me parece que son expresiones fijas, pero no entiendo a qué refiere "las".  ¿A "cosas"?

Comment: Siempre entendí que la alusión tácita alude a las  `maneras`  femenino plural. Se *las* ingenia (a las maneras) para...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He encontrado [este](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287444343_Locuciones_verbales_con_clitico_en_espanol_del_tipo_darsela) artículo que denomina estas expresiones como *locuciones verbales con pronombre clítico femenino* y que parece indicar que no hay una explicación completamente satisfactoria del fenómeno, aunque indica que puede tener relación con la abundancia de locuciones adverbiales en femenino que existen en castellano, por ejemplo, *a ciegas*, *a malas*, *a tientas*,...

El artículo tiene un anexo con muchas de estas locuciones verbales y en el texto se comparan con otras fórmulas similares. También se indica que, aunque en ocasiones sea posible saber cuál es el objeto al que *la* sustituye en la oración, esto no es siempre así o, aun siendo posible, no sería conocido por la mayoría de hablantes.

Por si el enlace dejara de funcionar, el artículo que menciono se titula "Locuciones verbales con clítico en español del tipo dársela" y está firmado por Mario García-Page de la UNED.

Comment: También pueden encontrarse muchas publicaciones con el término "Construcciones con clítico femenino lexicalizado".